# laravel auth:api returns SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where ``

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I get the following error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where
>   clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `` =
>   7pAJDfttBDr5tTJtkV0zQSE2QX1Zh8CFSycMaCg7yRmzHNyb5DAXATRp8gbs limit 1)

ActionsController.php

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Company;
    use App\User;
    use App\Company_User;
    use App\Company_Follower;
    use Auth;

    class ActionsController extends Controller
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            return $this->middleware('auth:api');
        }

        public function follow_company(Company $company)
        {

            return response()->json(['test' => auth()->id()]);
        }

    }
```

Routes\Api.php

```
route::any('companies/{company}/follow','ActionsController@follow_company')
->name('api.companies.follow');
```

url : http://test.loc/api/companies/1/follow?api_token=7pAJDfttBDr5tTJtkV0zQSE2QX1Zh8CFSycMaCg7yRmzHNyb5DAXATRp8gbs

Comment: Post your query

Comment: Maybe the "" ommit token in query. As @B001ᛦ post query, ->toSql()

Comment: Looks like it might be an issue in your guards array inside config/auth.php . Can you show what the array element with the key of "api" looks like ?

Comment: here is the api array        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

Comment: there is no any queries just this lines but if i changed the the guard of auth to web it works like charm

Comment: still can't solve it